# Regex optional condition in replace

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Input :

```
abc-AA-abc
abc+AA+abc
AA-abc
AA+abc
```

Output:

```
abc-{AA}-abc
abc+{AA}+abc
{AA}-abc 
{AA}+abc
```

I want to wrap AA when it is in between 2 special characters or when it is in the beginning of the string followed by a special character.

I am able to write regex to match the string using below:

```
Replace("((\W)(AA)(\W))|((AA)(\W))", "$1{$2}$3").
```

Above is working fine for first case. But its failing when the match is found at the beginning of the string.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/mtNbrt/1, use `\b` around the `AA` (`"\\bAA\\b"`) and replace with `"{$0}"`.

Comment: or use (^|\W) the ^ asserts you are at the beginning of the string.